# How to perform CRUD operation in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I need to write methods that will perform inserts and deletes in my EF database.

When I try to add new object I get the following erorr message:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.StudentCourses_dbo.Courses_CourseID". The conflict occurred in database "Demo.EmployeeDBcontext", table "dbo.Courses", column 'CourseID'.

My classes:

```
class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    publicIList<StudentCourse>StudentCourses { get; set; }
}

class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public IList<StudentCourse>StudentCourses { get; set; }
}

//Many to many entity
class StudentCourse
{
    //Navigation properties
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    //composite key
    [Key, Column (Order=1)]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column (Order=2)]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    public DateTime EnrolledDate { get; set; }
}
```

Main method:

```
using(var db = new EmployeeDBcontext())
{
    StudentCourse stcourse1 = new StudentCourse();

    Student st1 = new Student("Francis");
    Course  cs1 = new Course("Bio");

    stcourse1.StudentID = st1.StudentID;
    stcourse1.CourseID = cs1.CourseID;
    stcourse1.EnrolledDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);

    db.StudentCourses.Add(stcourse1);
    db.Courses.Add(cs1);
    db.Student.Add(st1);

    Student st2 = new Student("Jack");
    Course cs2 = new Course("Hist");

    db.Student.Add(newStud);
    db.Courses.Add(newCor);

    db.SaveChanges(); 

    //Method calls
    Remove(11)
    AddNew(st2 , cs2 , new DateTime(2018, 1, 1));
}
```

Method for removing from database:

```
public static void Remove(int csID)
{
    using (var db=new EmployeeDBcontext())
    {
        StudentCourse temp = new StudentCourse();

        foreach (var item in db.StudentCourses)
        {
           if(item.StudentID == csID )
           {
                temp = item;                        
           }
        }

        db.StudentCourses.Remove(temp);
        db.SaveChanges();
     } 
}
```

Method for adding new:

```
public static void AddNew(Student s, Course c,DateTime d)
{
   using (var db = new EmployeeDBcontext())
   {
      StudentCourse newCourse = new StudentCourse();
      newCourse.StudentID = s.StudentID;
      newCourse.CourseID = c.CourseID;
      newCourse.EnrolledDate = d;

      db.StudentCourses.Add(newCourse);

      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your table dbo.StudentCourses_dbo, it has a foreign key reference to another table.**You must build the table containing the Primary Key first. i.e dbo.Courses.**

Currently, You are trying to insert data in dbo.StudentCourses_dbo table which doesn't have CourseID reference in  dbo.Courses. i.e You must Insert Data into the parent table, containing the Primary Key, before attempting to insert data into the child table containing the Foreign Key.

So in Your example you have to create course entity first to add courses and then use created course id to add  student.This should resolve your issue. Hope this helps you.